# Adding an exit code to log file

Tags: cron, stdout, aws

I have created a bash script that runs automated EBS backups on AWS. It is kicked off via a cronjob:

`0 2 * * * /bin/bash /root/backup_snapshots.sh > backup.log 2>&1`

This works perfectly, but next thing I want to do is to add an exit code for whether or not the script runs successfully ( So I can configure a Nagios check on it). There is a few things I am going to be doing:

1. Create the backup.log in /var/log/backup/ directory.
2. Configure logrotate to rotate it daily, to make this check easier to
   detect.

But one question I have is, is it possible to have cron write an exit code to the backup.log file I created? Or should I go with this type of implementation:

Create crontab entry with a script that can kick off the actual script AND have an exit code like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
/root/backup_snapshots.sh 2> /dev/null
if [ $? -eq 0 ]
then
  echo "PASS"
else
  echo "FAIL" >&2
fi
```

I want to make this as simple as possible so if cron can do it, awesome! If not, would the next best thing would be to create a bash script that executes backup_snapshots.sh and run via cron?

Comment: I haven't used logger yet. Not sure how to really add logging to it via logger. But essentially, I need something in place that would add 3 codes.. One for pass, fail, and in_progress..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash
exec 1>/var/log/backup/backup_sbapshots.log 2>&1
if /root/backup_snapshots.sh
then
  echo "PASS"
else
  echo "FAIL"
fi
```

---

Make your cron script as shown which will put the cronjob run status in the backup log file. Note that there's no mention anywhere of the `$?` variable as  the `if` statement does it own it's own.

Comment: Thanks for this information. One question: when you use the exec command, should that be pointed to the actual script that runs the backups or the log file that is created?

Comment: `exec  ..` should be pointed to the logs or wherever you want the dumps from your script to be stored in. We `exec` once at the top to avoid having to do a redirection everytime the script outputs/errors something, as that sets the stage for all times to come during the script's run.